# Is there convenient way to get louder notifications for calendar events?

Tags: calendar, alarm

So basically I'd like to get reminders for important events in a smart way. So looking for these features.

1. Should have an alarm option (both silent and loud).
2. Ideally, this alarm should be escalating (starts out with vibrate but then becomes loud if not dismissed)
3. Have a smart option where it uses your current location along with the location of the event to time the alarm (so you can get to the event on time if you leave soon)

For the first feature, there are a few hacks (make a long sound file as your notification) but I currently use this app for this purpose.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.mildev84.reminder

Does anyone have any suggestions for better apps/setups that would give me the functionality I want?
I was actually thinking of even making the app myself (would be first app)